# VBA Adding a User Defined Control to Userform at Runtime

Tags: vba, excel, userform

So I've made the following control in Design Mode then added the control to a new page `Custom` in my toolbox.

Now, what would I use for the `progID` parameter in `Controls.Add()`? How do I look up this value? `Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1")` adds a regular frame, not the desired custom control.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you do not generate a new progID with a custom control. Per the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/add-a-modified-control-to-the-control-toolbox) for custom/modified controls:

> Note: When you drag a control onto the Control Toolbox, *you only transfer the advanced property values.*

So only the properties are transferred; the actual control is still of the same type/s as the one you created it from. Further, it looks like this progID is ["a unique system-wide string that the Windows operating system can use to identify your control's type."](http://www.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson4/p35.html) So unless you are up to coding your own control, it looks as though you're just passing properties to the custom toolbox controls you create there.

You'll have to just replicate the custom control each time you want to add it. Just create a sub with all the correct properties and call it. Not what you were looking for, but it'll get the job done.